# How to get last 12 digits from a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, truncate, gsub

How would I get last 12 digits of a string using mysql?

Let's say I have a varchar field with a tracking number, that may be anywhere from 5 to 20 varchars long.  But I only need to select last 12 digits or less if there are less.

so in a `field = 12345678123456789012`

I would only need to get what's in brackets

```
field = 12345678[123456789012]
```

I saw a few examples using mid, etc, but they dont' produce the desired result or I can't find an example that makes sense :-(

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SELECT RIGHT(field, 12);`

Comment: So obvious! Don't I feel stupid ( I just used same function  last week). Thanks James. Time to pack up and go home for the day.  :-)

Comment: @Nick:  No problem at all.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Nick,

Try using the RIGHT(str, len) function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right

I'm not sure of the semantics if the string is shorter than length as I don't have access to MySQL but it might do what you're looking for.